# title_prefix override to h1 instead of h2

Tags: panels, 7

How do I override the $title_prefix that is inherited from the value of

```
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h2>
```

in panels-pane.tpl.php page. This is normally output in the page.tpl.php but since i'm using panels it becomes the above.

My stating attempt is to write a template.php preprocess function, but this adds the code to every title in the template, and just adds the h1 to the page; it does not replace the h2 with the h1 for each page title. I don't want to touch the `$title` value which is h2 but change `$title_prefix`.

```
// Preprocess title prefix override. h1 instead of default h2
function at_panels_everywhere_preprocess(&$vars) {
  $vars['title_prefix'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<h1></h1>',
  );
}
```

I need to replace the `$title_prefix` ouput to be h1 not h2 and only for the title_prefix while within the #content region.

Answer (score 1):

Potential solutions that didn't work:

http://drupal.org/project/panel_variant_page_title 
Changing panels-pane-tpl.php h2 to h1 as this changes all panels not the 1 page panel that needs to be h1.

Eventual solution:

Turning off Page panel titles and just hardcoded h1 tag into body field. Not ideal but there really is no working solution apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `_preprocess` hook function if you are using panels to replace h2 with h1  because h2 is hard coded in the template file.

You need to copy `panels-pane.tpl.php` template file from `sites/all/modules/panels/templates` folder to your Drupal custom theme `sites/all/themes/CUSTOM_THEME/templates`.

Then edit `panels-pane.tpl.php` and change h2 to h1

```
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h2>
```

to

```
<h1<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h1>
```

Comment: I've done what you have recommended before asking, problem is this adds a h1 to all the panes and effectively the "page title" (title_prefix). So it reads h1 > h1, h1, h1 etc. Is there no way to set the $title_prefix separately from $title so it doesn't inherit it's value? Many thanks :)

Comment: well, you can play with panels-pane.tpl.php code the way you want. You can change/remove `$title_prefix` position they way you want it to look like. If you can post a screenshot for what you are looking to achieve it will be great.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post a image direct on here as I need a rep of 10. I've uploaded screenshots on dropbox instead. https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2q4rb176ucqrz6/panels-layout.png & https://www.dropbox.com/s/pjj071wz82fydwk/panels-firebug.png

Comment: I forgot to say thanks, so thanks in advance for this help, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but it looks like a good approach:

```
<?php if ($title): ?><?php if($display->title_pane == $pane->pid) : ?>
<h1 class="pane-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
<?php else : ?>
<h2 class="pane-title"><?php print $title; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

https://drupal.org/comment/4004824#comment-4004824

Comment: If you put above code into your panels-pane.tpl.php or whatever template you use on your site (below <?php if ($title): ?>, the title for the first node on your pane will have an <h1>.